# XMLSchema validation for StAX parser

Tags: java, xsd

In DOM or SAX parsers in Java it is possible to define the XML Schema to use by calling  methods DocumentBuilderFactory.setSchema(..) or SAXParserFactory.setSchema(...).

How can I do the similar thing (enable XML Schema validation) when using StAX parser? Actually I am creating the parser as follows:

```
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
factory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_NAMESPACE_AWARE, true);
XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(docIs);
parseDoc(reader); // own method which reads data from XML
```

and I would like to know when the XML document does not match schema or is invalid XML document.

Comment: Check Stax validation thread on stackoverflow-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793087/stax-xml-validation

Comment: Thank you for the link. It explains everything.

Answer (score 0):

[XMLBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/) has a tool for this. Check out StreamInstanceValidator which makes use of 
ValidatingXMLStreamReader .

svn.apache.org/viewvc/xmlbeans/trunk/src/xmlcomp/org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/tool/StreamInstanceValidator.java?view=markup

svn.apache.org/viewvc/xmlbeans/trunk/src/typeimpl/org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/validator/ValidatingInfoXMLStreamReader.java?view=markup

Comment: Could you please add an essential piece of code that shows how to implement this?