# StAXSource not accepted by validator in JBoss EAP 6.1

Tags: jboss, xml-parsing, jboss6.x, xml-validation, stax

Issue while Validating `StAXSource` in JBoss Server,
**What I Tried:**
I try to do parsing and validation at a time using StAX.
As described in this [**example**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13427581/1213738).

I am able to execute the program as standalone application,
 but when I try it as a web application in `JBoss EAP 6.1` server got below exception.

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Source parameter of type      
javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXSource' is not accepted by this validator.
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.ValidatorImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
```

There are multiple frame works modified from StAXSource to StreamSource, 
[TEIID-2046](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/TEIID-2046), [activiti](http://forums.activiti.org/content/staxsource-exception-512-default-war)..etc.
I am not sure, Why JBoss is not supporting StAXSource, any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue got resolved by adding xercesImpl 2.11.0 dependency. (as mentioned in [forums_activiti](http://forums.activiti.org/content/staxsource-exception-512-default-war))
**Solution:** add `xerces 2.11.0` dependency.

```
<dependency>         
   <groupId>xerces</groupId>         
   <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
   <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Details:**
JBoss EAP 6.1 has Xerces 2.9.1-redhat-4, but StaxSource enhancement released in Xerces-J 2.10.0 (For more details refer [JBoss EAP Component details](https://access.redhat.com/site/articles/112673)).
[**Xerces-J 2.10.0**](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.commons.general/1770) has implementation enhancement for `java.xml.validation` and supporting `StAXSource` for JAXP validator.
[image]

**Update:** Added [**Feature Request** in JBoss EAP 1.6](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-41) project.

**References:**
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.commons.general/1770
http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/
http://people.apache.org/~edwingo/jaxp-faq.html