# xml validation with StAX: Unrecognized property 'javax.xml.stream.isInterning'

Tags: java, xml, validation, jboss

I'm trying to get xml validation working with StAXin our jboss webapp.  I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793087/stax-xml-validation) and followed the example.  I then saw the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Source parameter of type      
javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXSource' is not accepted by this validator.
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.ValidatorImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
```

As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20493359/staxsource-not-accepted-by-validator-in-jboss-eap-6-1), the problem here was that jboss 5.0.1 has an old version of xerces.  So I upgraded it to 2.11.0 by replacing the existing xercesImpl.jar under `jboss-5.0.1.GA/lib/endorsed/` .  Then jboss wouldn't start, because of the following error:

```
NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
```

As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515333/noclassdeffounderror-org-w3c-dom-elementtraversal), in newer versions of xerces the classes have been split out to a separate jar file: xml-apis.jar .  I took the latest version of that file (1.4.01, dated December 2009) from [the xerces homepage](http://xerces.apache.org/mirrors.cgi#binary) and added it to `jboss-5.0.1.GA//lib/endorsed/` - and now jboss starts ok.

So far so good.

But now I am seeing the following error when I attempt to call the `javax.xml.validation.Validator.validate()` method:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized property 'javax.xml.stream.isInterning'
```

There seems to be no existing problem on SO which refers to that property.  Surely I can't be the only person trying to do xml validation with StAX on jboss 5 ?!

Or am I doing something obviously wrong?

Code snippet:

```
 Validator validator = requestSchema.newValidator();  
 StAXSource source = new StAXSource(xmlsr);  //an XMLStreamReader
 validator.validate(source);
```

Comment: from the gist of it, if i'm not mistaken the library you're using has an obsolete version of
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader which has no property "isinterning". hope this helps just a bit, as I really don't know which jar is bringing this class to your specific case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found two solutions to this problem.

One option is to thinly wrap the XmlStreamReader in a new class which will ignore the `getProperty` call if the parameter is `"javax.xml.stream.isInterning"`, and delegate it otherwise.

Another option is to use an XmlEventReader instead, which is less performant but works without requiring a custom wrapper.